# Remove spaces from std::string in C++

Tags: c++, string, stl, whitespace

What is the preferred way to remove spaces from a string in C++? I could loop through all the characters and build a new string, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

The best thing to do is to use the algorithm [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and isspace:

```
remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace);
```

Now the algorithm itself can't change the container(only modify the values), so it actually shuffles the values around and returns a pointer to where the end now should be. So we have to call string::erase to actually modify the length of the container:

```
str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());
```

We should also note that remove_if will make at most one copy of the data. Here is a sample implementation:

```
template<typename T, typename P>
T remove_if(T beg, T end, P pred)
{
    T dest = beg;
    for (T itr = beg;itr != end; ++itr)
        if (!pred(*itr))
            *(dest++) = *itr;
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Because 'isspace' has overloads, you will probably need to qualify the generic code to use ::isspace (the C implementation that doesn't take a locale) or be greeted with cryptic template instantiation errors.

Comment: All - be wary of the above method (The two single lines, not the templated version, although it may have the same issue).  I used it in a project without realizing that it isn't always correct.  For example, if you pass it the string "1 + 1" it returns "1+11".  

I switched to @rupello 's method below and it worked fine for this case.  Happy coding!

Comment: @Joe The answer explicitly mentions that you need to call `erase` afterwards. That will return the correct result.

Comment: -1 this use of `isspace` is UB for all character sets except original 7-bit ASCII. C99 §7.4/1. it *does not surprise* me that it's been upvoted to the tune of 71 votes by now, in spite of being Very Bad Advice.

Comment: I don't know why but remove_if wrks incorrect in OS X

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: c99 `isspace()` accepts any `int` value representable as `unsigned char` (+EOF). I don't see UB for `std::string`. What am I missing here?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you're simply missing that with most every (if not just "every") extant C++ compiler, `char` is by default a *signed integer* type. Thus for non-ASCII characters you get negative values. E.g., with Latin-1 and the default signedness choice, Norwegian characters ÆØÅ and æøå are negative.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: No information is lost: `char -> int`. All `signed char` are "representable" as `unsigned char`. [`::isspace()` returns the same result with gcc, clang -std=c++11](https://gist.github.com/zed/ba2de81701a187cbbd83). Are you saying that "most every" C++ compiler doesn't include gcc, clang? Or they  doesn't follow the standard on some other (not mine) system?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: when you pass a negative value except EOF, to `isspace`, you have Undefined Behavior. because the C++ standard says so, by way of incorporating the C standard. it's as simple as that. you might relate that back to your argument (which has a different conclusion) to identify the flaw or flaws. anyway the code in this answer passes negative values for all non-ASCII characters, with the default signedness of `char`. Thus it has **Undefined Behavior**, which *can* have the effect that you naïvely and incorrectly expect. That's basic knowledge.

Comment: To try it out you can experiment with different character classification functions in debug builds with Visual C++. Some of the implementations are table-driven and will crash on non-EOF negative arguments. That's what having UB means: that in some cases, with some compilers or context, you get some other behavior than what you naïvely and incorrectly expect, i.e. non-portable code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: *"because the C++ standard says so"* -- where does it say it? We already established that `C99 §7.4/1` doesn't say it unless you claim that `char` is not representable as `unsigned char`. I've tested that both gcc and clang produce the expected result (`isspace()` has the same value for `char` and `unsigned char`) on my machine. Does [the code](https://gist.github.com/zed/ba2de81701a187cbbd83) fail on Visual C++? Also, Microsoft is a "standard" but it is not C++11 standard.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: about half of the `signed char` values are not representable as `unsigned char` in the meaning of representable employed by the standard. the same terminology is used for conversion from unsigned to signed, where "otherwise, the value is implementation-defined" (C++11 §4.7/3). thus you are effectively claiming that the word representable, used about the same thing, means two entirely different things in two different parts of the standard. if so then that's a hitherto unknown defect in the standard. you should report it.

Comment: Just to repeat, the code in this answer passes negative values (different from EOF) to `isspace`, for all non-ASCII characters, with the in-practice default choice of signedness for `char`. Thus it has **undefined behavior**. I'm repeating it because I suspect a deliberate attempt to drown that fact in noise.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: you are right. +1. It is **undefined behavior** to pass a negative `int` that is not `EOF` to `isspace()` in C11. It took me asking the question [what does “representable” mean in C11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25776824/4279) to understand. "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity" :)

Comment: Not only that, I think that MSVC actually asserts on this fact mean that your program _will_ crash if you do this for some input.

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’`

Comment: `No matching function for call to 'remove_if'` even included the algorithm library.

Comment: Will this be quicker than regex_replace(inputString,"\\s+", "")?

Comment: Gee imagine if C++ supported str.replace(" ", ""); How life would be much simpler!

Comment: For those who don't want to remove new lines but only tabs and spaces a simpler function `::isblank` would work well. 
Note: It would still have the unsigned char UB though.

Answer (score 136):

```
std::string::iterator end_pos = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ');
str.erase(end_pos, str.end());
```

Comment: My up-vote for the canonical erase/remove idiom.  Can be made into a one liner:

str.erase (std::remove (str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

Comment: Note: You need to include `<algorithm>` for this to work.

Answer (score 43):

From [gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=359650)

```
string.erase(std::remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(), std::isspace), string.end());
```

Comment: This will not compile on standards-conforming implementations because of the locale-taking overloads of std::isspace.  You'll need to use ::isspace or perform some unreadable machinations with std::bind2nd.  Isn't generic code beautiful?

Comment: Also note that if any of the characters is negative (eg a UTF8 char when char is signed), use of `::isspace` is UB.

Comment: C++17 solution: `string.erase(std::remove_if(string.begin(), string.end(), [](unsigned char x) { return std::isspace(x); }), string.end());`

Answer (score 34):

Can you use Boost String Algo? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1290573

```
erase_all(str, " ");
```

Comment: It is slower than the `remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace);` that Matt Price mentioned. I don't know why.
Actually, all the boost stuff, that have STL alternatives, are slower than the corresponding gcc ones (All the ones I tested). Some of them are immensely slower! (up to 5 times in unordered_map inserts)
Maybe it is because of the CPU cache of the shared environment or something like it.

Answer (score 23):

You can use this solution for removing a char:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), char_to_remove), str.end());
```

Comment: #include < string.h > using namespace std;

Comment: This solution is correct for me. The top one is not.

Comment: using namespace std should be avoided. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 18):

For trimming, use [boost string algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/string_algo.html):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

// ...

string str1(" hello world! ");
trim(str1);      // str1 == "hello world!"
```

Answer (score 12):

Hi, you can do something like that. This function deletes all spaces.

```
string delSpaces(string &str) 
{
   str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
   return str;
}
```

---

I made another function, that deletes all unnecessary spaces.

```
string delUnnecessary(string &str)
{
    int size = str.length();
    for(int j = 0; j<=size; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <=j; i++)
        {
            if(str[i] == ' ' && str[i+1] == ' ')
            {
                str.erase(str.begin() + i);
            }
            else if(str[0]== ' ')
            {
                str.erase(str.begin());
            }
            else if(str[i] == '\0' && str[i-1]== ' ')
            {
                str.erase(str.end() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

In C++20 you can use free function std::erase

```
std::string str = " Hello World  !";
std::erase(str, ' ');
```

Full example:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = " Hello World  !";
    std::erase(str, ' ');
    std::cout << "|" << str <<"|";
}
```

I print | so that it is obvious that space at the begining is also removed.

note: this removes only the space, not every other possible character that may be considered whitespace, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace

Answer (score 8):

```
string replaceinString(std::string str, std::string tofind, std::string toreplace)
{
        size_t position = 0;
        for ( position = str.find(tofind); position != std::string::npos; position = str.find(tofind,position) )
        {
                str.replace(position ,1, toreplace);
        }
        return(str);
}
```

use it:

```
string replace = replaceinString(thisstring, " ", "%20");
string replace2 = replaceinString(thisstring, " ", "-");
string replace3 = replaceinString(thisstring, " ", "+");
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to do this with an easy macro, here's one:

```
#define REMOVE_SPACES(x) x.erase(std::remove(x.begin(), x.end(), ' '), x.end())
```

This assumes you have done `#include <string>` of course.

Call it like so:

```cpp
std::string sName = " Example Name ";
REMOVE_SPACES(sName);
printf("%s",sName.c_str()); // requires #include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: why would you use a macro for this?

Comment: Less keyboard typing for a common task.

Comment: Equally short for the call-site is calling a _function_ taking a lvalue-reference to a string.  Macros can have surprising behaviors interacting with their arguments (esp with side effects), but worse, if they're involved in an error, their names do not show up in compiler messages, their implementation does.

Comment: Yes - macros can make debugging and maintenance very difficult. In a small program, maybe they're OK. In a multi-million line application with hundreds of projects, macros can really be a pain.

Answer (score 4):

Removes all [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Whitespace) such as tabs and line breaks (C++11):

```
string str = " \n AB cd \t efg\v\n";
str = regex_replace(str,regex("\\s"),"");
```

Comment: Why would you recommend this approach over @Matt-Price‘s accepted answer from over a decade ago?

Comment: Let all solutions be presented here. Maybe someone will need this solution.

Comment: I’m not arguing against that. I’m saying make it easier for people to assess different approaches by explaining the differences and what scenarios they might be better suited for.

Comment: Probably this solution is not the most economical, but it allows you to get rid of all [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Whitespace)  '\s', not just spaces ' '.

Answer (score 3):

> ```cpp
>    #include <algorithm>
>    using namespace std;
>
>    int main() {
>        .
>        .
>        s.erase( remove( s.begin(), s.end(), ' ' ), s.end() );
>        .
>        .
>    }
> ```

---

### Source:

Reference taken from [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/9557/) forum.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything more than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83481/11384392) already does. Is there more explanation or detail you could add to make your answer higher quality and worth keeping on this question?

Comment: I think it's more _simpler_, 'cause it does the same thing in one statement.

Comment: Great! Then put that reasoning as an explanation *directly in your answer*. The original question is more than *eleven years old*, and without a justification your answer could get seen as noise when compared to the other accepted, well-upvoted answers. Having that explanation will help keep your answer from being removed.

Comment: That would be _good_ but I couldn't get that how should I put _that_ into my answer... _that my answer is better than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83481/11384392)._? It would be a great pleasure if you could _edit_ my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59053051/edit) to add that content myself would go against the [editing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), and my edit would likely get declined or rolled back later. You can use the first link in this comment to edit the answer yourself. It's totally acceptable to state that you think your answer is better than some other one, and provide justification for it. The community will decide whether you're right by upvoting or downvoting.

Comment: _Thanks_ @Das_Geek

Comment: Please someone explain how the above line remove the spaces.What is the execution flow.??

Answer (score 2):

I used the below work around for long - not sure about its complexity.

`s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char s,char f){return (f==' '||s==' ');}),s.end());`

when you wanna remove character `' '` and some for example `-`  use

`s.erase(std::unique(s.begin(),s.end(),[](char s,char f){return ((f==' '||s==' ')||(f=='-'||s=='-'));}),s.end());`

likewise just increase the `||` if number of characters you wanna remove is not 1

but as mentioned by others the erase remove idiom also seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
string removeSpaces(string word) {
    string newWord;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word[i] != ' ') {
            newWord += word[i];
        }
    }

    return newWord;
}
```

This code basically takes a string and iterates through every character in it. It then checks whether that string is a white space, if it isn't then the character is added to a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, as other answers are much better than this.

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/functional/partial.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/range/conversion.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
int main() {
    using ranges::to;
    using ranges::views::filter;
    using boost::hana::partial;
    auto const& not_space = partial(std::not_equal_to<>{}, ' ');
    auto const& to_string = to<std::string>;

    std::string input = "2C F4 32 3C B9 DE";
    std::string output = input | filter(not_space) | to_string;
    assert(output == "2CF4323CB9DE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string str = "2C F4 32 3C B9 DE";
  str.erase(remove(str.begin(),str.end(),' '),str.end());
  cout << str << endl;
```

output: 2CF4323CB9DE

Answer (score 0):

I created a function, that removes the white spaces from the either ends of string. Such as
`"  Hello World   "`, will be converted into `"Hello world"`.

This works similar to `strip`, `lstrip` and `rstrip` functions, which are frequently used in python.

```
string strip(string str) {
    while (str[str.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        str = str.substr(0, str.length() - 1);
    }
    while (str[0] == ' ') {
        str = str.substr(1, str.length() - 1);
    }
    return str;
}

string lstrip(string str) {
    while (str[0] == ' ') {
        str = str.substr(1, str.length() - 1);
    }
    return str;
}

string rstrip(string str) {
    while (str[str.length() - 1] == ' ') {
        str = str.substr(0, str.length() - 1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string removespace(string str)
{    
    int m = str.length();
    int i=0;
    while(i<m)
    {
        while(str[i] == 32)
        str.erase(i,1);
        i++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: It is generally preferred that you add a brief explanation to code answers.

Comment: @test - `length()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. `erase()` takes a `size_type`, not an `int`. The function will probably fail if two consecutive spaces are encountered since the index is always incremented. If one space is removed, then the loop will read beyond the string's bounds. You should probably delete this answer since it needs a lot of help.

Answer (score -3):

I'm afraid it's the best solution that I can think of. But you can use reserve() to pre-allocate the minimum required memory in advance to speed up things a bit. You'll end up with a new string that will probably be shorter but that takes up the same amount of memory, but you'll avoid reallocations.

EDIT: Depending on your situation, this may incur less overhead than jumbling characters around.

You should try different approaches and see what is best for you: you might not have any performance issues at all.

Comment: remove_if makes at most one copy of each value. So there really isn't that much overhead relative to what needs to be done.