# The code is supposed to return string without spaces, but it returns string until first space character

Tags: c++, string

I'm making a console calculator, and I want to remove any whitespace that the user might enter while using the program. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    std::cout<<"Enter sum): ";
    cin>>str;
     str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), (int(*)(int))isspace), str.end());
    cout<<str;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

if i entered 2 + 2   =, output should be 2+2=
but the output is: 2
am i using the wrong function here?

Comment: Maybe this can help?

[Remove spaces from std::string in C++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `remove_if` and `erase` is fine.  Your method for getting input is not.  `operator>>` is whitespace delimited.  Use `getline` instead.

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    std::cout<<"Enter sum): ";
    getline(cin,str);
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), (int(*)(int))isspace), str.end());
    cout<<str;    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with getting the user input, not with stripping the spaces.

The code that removes spaces is correct, as you can [see for yourself on IDEone](http://www.ideone.com/LYJHL).

The problem is that operator `std::istream::operator >>` stops reading input on encountering the first whitespace character. You should use another function (such as [`getLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykfk8bc0.aspx)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function I wrote:

```
std::string& ReplaceAll(std::string& sS, const std::string& sWhat, const std::string& sReplacement) 
{
    size_t pos = 0, fpos;
    while ((fpos = sS.find(sWhat, pos)) != std::string::npos) 
    {
        sS.replace(fpos, sWhat.size(), sReplacement);
        pos = fpos + sReplacement.size();
    }
    return sS;
}
```

You can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Your function does the same thing as [`boost::algorithm::replace_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_all.html), but in a far less efficient manner.