# Strip / remove symbols from userinput in C++

Tags: c++, string, ascii

Here's what I have so far:

```
string stripSymbols(string str) {
    int stringSize = strlen(str.c_str());

    for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++)
        if (str[i] == 0x46)
            str[i] = 0x32;
    return str;
}
```

I know the ascii codes are probably wrong. That's part of the problem. But once I figure those  out, I was thinking I could maybe put a switch in here for each symbol that would replace each symbol with an empty space.

Or better yet, I could have a for loop in my for loop that loops through a string of symbols and replaces any that match with the user's input with an empty space.

I have a couple ideas, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

**Update 1:**

This code looks a little better and works:

```
string stripSymbols(string str) {
    int stringSize = str.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringSize; i++)
        if (str[i] == '.')
            str[i] = ' ';
    return str;
}
```

But the replies offer a more efficient solution.

**Update 2:**

Solution inspired by Kerrek SB's reply:

```
char symbols [] = {'!', '?', ',', '\'', '.'};
int symbols_size = sizeof(symbols) / sizeof(char);  

for (int j = 0; j < symbols_size; j++)
    replace(str.begin(), str.end(), symbols[j], ' ');
```

Comment: If you are not sure about the ASCII codes, why not use literal chars instead of using numerical codes and hoping they're correct?

Comment: Jeez... who gave you the idea to write `strlen(str.c_str())`??? How about `str.size()`?

Comment: I agree with previous comments, I will just add: You could pass `str` by reference and not return anything. From what I understand you were going to use your function like this: `str = stripSymbols(str);`.

Comment: By the way, `0x46 == 'F'` and `0x32 == '2'`. Do you intend to replace all each "F" with a "2"?

Comment: You probably want decimal 46 (`'.'`) and 32 (`' '`); using character literals instead of magic numbers makes it much easier both to read and to write.

Comment: @KerrekSB Fixed. I have no experience with dealing with string operations in C++, so bare with me...

Comment: @Rob I wanted to replace a period with a space. And Mike, your suggestion of using char literals helped. I forgot there's a subtle difference between defining a string and char in C++. I was using " " which resulted in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were going for a robust solution I'd probably just use `boost::regex_replace`:

```
// regex with illegal characters
std::string output = boost::regex_replace(str, "[!@#%]", " ");
```

[Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to replace any non-alphanumeric character with a space:

```
std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c){return !std::isalnum(c);}, ' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) and [`string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something like this:

```
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), 0x46, 0x32);
```

You can do this in the original context even, no need for a separate function. You need to `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: I ended up using this solution with a for loop. Very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wishing to just remove/replace every instance of a specific character from a `std::string`? If so, see these similar questions:

[How to replace all occurrences of a character in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896600/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-character-in-string)

[Remove spaces from std::string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)

And just use the concepts displayed in the answers to suit your own goals.