# remove whitespace in std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, removing-whitespace

In C++, what's an easy way to turn:

This std::string

```
\t\tHELLO WORLD\r\nHELLO\t\nWORLD     \t
```

Into:

```
HELLOWORLDHELLOWORLD
```

Comment: @tomislav-maric I don't think it's a duplicate of that post, the OP there was working with a `cin` stream, and thus using iostream functions.

Comment: similar but not exact duplicate, so not voting to close.

Comment: @CashCow I checked it again.. you are right, sorry about that.

Comment: See also [Remove spaces from std::string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Simple combination of [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

Not totally safe version

```
s.erase( std::remove_if( s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace ), s.end() );
```

For safer version replace `::isspace` with

```
std::bind( std::isspace<char>, _1, std::locale::classic() )
```

(Include all relevant headers)

For a version that works with alternative character types replace `<char>` with `<ElementType>` or whatever your templated character type is. You can of course also replace the locale with a different one. If you do that, beware to avoid the inefficiency of recreating the locale facet too many times.

In C++11 you can make the safer version into a lambda with:

```
[]( char ch ) { return std::isspace<char>( ch, std::locale::classic() ); }
```

Comment: @chris `::isspace` includes the new line as well: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/

Comment: it will. isspace will return true for newlines.

Comment: `isspace` has UB for all characters except those in the basic something something. C99 §7.4/1.

Comment: How did you perform your output? Are you sure you didn't stick one in e.g .(std::cout << s << std::endl)

Comment: Never mind, it was me being completely stupid and not passing the second argument to `erase` (I typed one up before the answer).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes does C99 standard apply to C++? C++ has its own standard.

Comment: C++98 delegates the behaviour of the C standard library to C89, and C++11 delegates the behaviour of the C standard library to C99.

Comment: @chris Yes as std::remove_if returns an iterator, and erase has an overload for a single iterator, it will indeed compile and not give you the result you want if you forget the second s.end()

Comment: @CashCow, I know, it's completely irritating when you forget it. In my case, I never saw the second argument when reading it how many times before I finally used it, so it's still wired in my brain that it only takes one.

Comment: Presumably the -1 from Mr Fernandes for use of ::isspace. perhaps he will enlighten us as to the special locale-based / character-set-based? You know for perfect UTF-8 it is not necessarily even a character-char one-to-one relationship so no functor / lambda will work here officially.

The only thing that will work for perfect UTF-8 iteration that might be multi-character is a custom iterator.

Comment: FWIW, all the whitespace characters in the example are encoded as single byte sequences in UTF-8, so yes, a simple lambda works for UTF-8.

Comment: You are saying that what looks like a whitespace will never appear as part of a multibyte character? I don't know the UTF-8 standard. The only thing I see as "undefined" are things like &nbsp; (non-breaking space) which is commonly ASCII 160 (or 0xA0) but might vary in other character sets.

Comment: My apologies. I got slightly confused about the true nature of the problem :) I knew using isspace was wrong, but I got confused as to the why. The why is related to `isspace` taking an `int` and to `char` being signed. Here is a small program that explains the issue http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=817f92f4a2482e5da0b7533285e53edb.

Comment: (And as a side note, NBSP is not in ASCII. ASCII has only 128 values).

Comment: (And note how this is not about multibyte encodings; any byte with a value higher than 0x7F in the source, *regardless of encoding* will trigger this issue; even single byte encodings like Latin-1 or Windows-1252 will cause it. Only 7-bit encodings like ASCII work fine)

Comment: Ok I have given the alternative answer that uses std::isspace with a locale.

Comment: Doesn't the lambda version require a "return" statement?

Comment: For C++ newbies like me 
_1 is from std::placeholders, and represent future arguments

Answer (score 13):

If C++03

```
struct RemoveDelimiter
{
  bool operator()(char c)
  {
    return (c =='\r' || c =='\t' || c == ' ' || c == '\n');
  }
};

std::string s("\t\tHELLO WORLD\r\nHELLO\t\nWORLD     \t");
s.erase( std::remove_if( s.begin(), s.end(), RemoveDelimiter()), s.end());
```

Or use C++11 lambda

```
s.erase(std::remove_if( s.begin(), s.end(), 
     [](char c){ return (c =='\r' || c =='\t' || c == ' ' || c == '\n');}), s.end() );
```

PS. [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) is used

Answer (score 4):

c++11

```
std::string input = "\t\tHELLO WORLD\r\nHELLO\t\nWORLD     \t";

auto rs = std::regex_replace(input,std::regex("\\s+"), "");

std::cout << rs << std::endl;
```

> /tmp ❮❮❮ ./play

```
HELLOWORLDHELLOWORLD
```

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you can use a lambda rather than using std::bind:

```
str.erase(
    std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
        [](char c) -> bool
        { 
            return std::isspace<char>(c, std::locale::classic()); 
        }), 
    str.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Boost.Algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/erase_all.html)'s `erase_all`

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/erase.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Hello World!";
    // or the more expensive one-liner in case your string is const
    // std::cout << boost::algorithm::erase_all_copy(s, " ") << "\n";
    boost::algorithm::erase_all(s, " "); 
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

NOTE: as is mentioned in the comments: `trim_copy` (or its cousins `trim_copy_left` and `trim_copy_right`) only remove whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: I saw some solutions that used Boost, but I'm not after a `trim` function, trimming I believe is doing something like `XX___XX_` -> `XX_XX` whereas I want the final solution to be `XXXX`.

Answer (score 2):

Stepping through it character by character and using [`string::erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) should work fine.

```
void removeWhitespace(std::string& str) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ' || str[i] == '\n' || str[i] == '\t') {
            str.erase(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work when there are adjacent space characters. The first one is erased, moving the second one down to position `i`. Then you go around the loop, increment `i`, and never check the second one.

Comment: You're right.  Fixed it.