# Remove whitespace in C++ string doesn't work

Tags: c++, macos, clion, removing-whitespace

I have read these two questions already:

1. [Remove spaces from std::string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)
2. [remove whitespace in std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233065/remove-whitespace-in-stdstring)

For some reason, I can never get the solutions to work correctly. In my program, I collect input from the user and pass it to an `std::string`. From there, I want to remove all of the spaces in it. For example, if the user inputs "3 + 2", I would like it to change to "3+2".

What happens is, whatever is before the first string is kept. Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string GetUserInput() {
    std::cout << "Please enter what you would like to calculate: ";
    std::string UserInput;
    std::cin >> UserInput;
    return UserInput;
}
int PerformCalculation(std::string Input) {
    Input.erase(std::remove_if(Input.begin(), Input.end(), ::isspace), Input.end());
    std::cout << Input;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    std::string CalculationToBePerformed = GetUserInput();
    int Solution = PerformCalculation(CalculationToBePerformed);
    return 0;
}
```

So when I run this program and type in "3 + 2", the output is "3".

Here is my console:

```
Please enter what you would like to calculate: 3 + 2
3
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I cannot figure out how to resolve this. I even tried using a solution that involved using a regex to remove all the `\s` characters, and that gave me the same issue.

Comment: Step through with a debugger and you should see your real problem.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, I am not quite sure how to do this. What is meant by reference instead of value?

Comment: As a general guideline - if the output of your function isn't what you expect, a good place to start is if the input to your function is what you expect.

Comment: @user2491647 - passing by reference won't affect this, so don't worry about it. The problem is with the input, not how it's handled. Look at the value of `UserInput` after the extraction from `cin`.

Comment: @PeteBecker & @Barry Thank you for this suggestion. It has helped me to learn about the use of `cin`

Comment: @user2491647 Next time try to produce a [mcve] (as you should) and you might even figure out the bug by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the complete line (up to terminating \n), you need to use e.g. `std::getline(std::cin, UserInput);`. Otherwise, you're currently reading text up to first whitespace character.

Comment: Thank you for a direct answer. As someone who has just started learning programming in C++ by following an online tutorial, this answer helps me a lot more than a vague answer that doesn't explain the problem!

Comment: @user2491647 the "vague answers" you mention are actually attempts to make you _think_, instead of just giving you the direct answer, that will be useless for your next question.