# Removing White Spaces

Tags: c++

I use the following to remove spaces from my variable

```
        for (i=0, ptr=lpsz;ptr[i];ptr++)
        {
            if (*ptr == ' ')
                i++;

            *ptr = ptr[i];
        }
        *ptr=0;
```

It seems to be having problems when there is more than one space however and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: It replaces a space with the next character in the string and then moves onto the character *after* the replacement. The replacement character is never checked.

Comment: @xen-0 thank you. My string is like `hello world today`. and after it reads `helloworldoday` missing the first letter of the third word. As a newbie im confused..lol

Comment: Misread the problem; formulating answer now.

Comment: @xen-0 I realize my error of wording in my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  It's much easier to think about two pointers moving through the string than one pointer plus an offset.

```
auto sptr = lpsz;
auto dptr = lpsz;
while (*dptr = *sptr) { // copy up to and including terminating NUL
    if (*dptr != ' ') dptr++; // but spaces take no slots in the destination
    sptr++;
}
```

- Demo: http://ideone.com/Pmmc20

or even

```
auto sptr = lpsz;
auto dptr = lpsz;
while (auto c = *dptr = *sptr) {
    dptr += (c != ' ');
    sptr++;
}
```

The essential difference between this and the original code is that when we see something other than a space, both mine and the original move the read and write location forward one.  But when we see a space, I move the read position forward by 1 and don't move the write position, while the original moves the read position forward by 2 and the write position forward by one, which skips a character.  Also, the original is testing at the write location for a space, instead of at the read location (mine tests the write location, but it does so *after copying the character from the read location*, so the result is correct).

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you use [`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) instead of doing your pointer magic.

If you use a `std::string` in combination with `std::isspace` you can do something like this:

```
std::string str = "Hello World Today";

str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)

A string really is just a container of characters, and therefore you can apply the erase/remove idiom to it.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Really, it is `remove_if` that is replacing the pointer magic.

Comment: Note that this code is **not** safe and can result in undefined behavior, e.g., when using it with my name! The problem is that the `std::isspace()` and family accepts only positive arguments but `char` may be signed. You need to use something like similar to `[](unsigned char c){ return std::isspace(c); }`. Of course, to replace the original code, `std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' ')` would work.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Thanks for that note. Interesting.

Comment: Thank you will try to implement :)

Comment: @DietmarKühl You do realize since you mentioned that very fact to me in comment to one of my answers a *year* ago I have *never* seen you're name on a question or answer and not thought back about it. Talk about getting into a guys head =P

Comment: @WhozCraig: You are basically saying I'm now the `<cctype>`-guy in your mind? Although it could be worth, I do think that I have a few more areas of expertise than just that but possibly this particular area is the overlap over our interests.

Comment: @DietmarKühl No doubt. You've expertise-o-plenty. I'm saying after you pointed this out in one of my answers a long time ago just *seeing your name on a question/answer* reminds me to never make that mistake again. Don't think of pink elephants. Too late. =P

Comment: I thought of pink elephants and they were incredibly pink. :)

Comment: @TonyTheLion *Exactly*.

Comment: the only problem with isspace is that it considers only whitespace characters in the C locale, hence it's not Unicode safe.

Answer (score 1):

You should use algorithms for this, as they are well tested. But if you want to analyze your code and understand the failure consider a high level description of what your code is running (See Tony's answer).

You maintain two indices into the buffer, one for reading and one for writing. Whenever the reading head detects a space you move it but skip the write. If the character is not a space you use the read head to get a value and write it through the write head.

In your implementation the read head is `ptr+i`, which is spelled a bit strange as an offset from the write head (as in `ptr[i]`). The write head is `ptr` (`*ptr =`). But your test in the loop is using the *write* head instead of the *read* head: `if (*ptr==' ')`.

Even if you fix this, the implementation has other issues, like for example the fact that if there are two consecutive spaces, since you do a single test in the loop. A rewrite of your algorithm could be:

```
char* remove_spaces(char* buffer) {
   char *read = buffer;
   for (char *read = buffer; (*read), ++read) {
      if (*read != ' ') {      // copy element
         *buffer = *read;
         ++buffer;             // and increment write head
      }
   }
   *buffer = 0;                // ensure null termination
   return read;
}
```

Now, the algorithm can be further improved (performance) by removing the number of writes to memory if you do an initial search for the first space and use that as the starting point for the loop above. That will reduce the number of operations and the number of cache lines that are marked dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Step through your loop carefully.

`i` is set to 0 at the start of the loop.
For the first space encountered, `i` is incremented (so `i==1`). The character at `ptr` is replaced with the character at `prt+i`, which is the next character. This works the first time, because `i` is 1.

But for the second space, `i` is set to 2 (since it's incremented), so the space is replaced by the character at `ptr+2`

It would be much easier to do this as part of a string copy, rather than an in-place alteration.
`dest` is a destination buffer for our altered copy.

```
for(ptr = lpsz; *ptr; ptr++){
    if(' ' == *ptr) {continue;}
    *dest = *ptr;
    dest++;
}
*dest = 0;
```

Comment: That it will. Which is amusing, because I picked up on that in the original code too. Edited code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'd rather say it doesn't do anything special with spaces but it does whatever it does with zeros ;) (when you wrote your comment and I wrote this comment originally)