# Ignoring whitespaces/tabs/newlines with getline()

Tags: c++, stl

I went through lot of the resources on web but still not able to get this. I didn't understand how 
std::skipws works to ignore whitespaces , tabs and newlines.

Following is my simple code

```
vector<string> vec;
while(1){

    getline(cin, s); 

    if( s.compare("#") == 0)
        break;
    else
        vec.push_back(s);
}
```

I will enter a line of strings with newlines, whitespaces and tabs. After input I want to store strings into the vector and that will stop when "#" string is encountered. I tried with the above code but it store spaces along with the strings in the vector though it terminates after enterting "#".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `std::getline` is to read an entire line, including whitespace, into a string buffer.

If you want to read tokens from a stream, skipping whitespace, then use the standard input operator `>>`.

```
std::vector<std::string> vec;
std::string s;
while(std::cin >> s && s != "#") {
    vec.push_back(s);
}
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/1ChePP)

Answer (score 0):

`std::skipws` is skipping only the leading whitespace characters in any input stream. It therefore has no effect on all the whitespaces after the first non-whitespace. If you want to read whole lines with `getline(cin, s)` you might as well consider removing the blanks and tabs that have been read from the string before pushing it into the container like so :

```
while (1){
    getline(cin, s);
    if (s.compare("#") == 0) {
        break;
    }
    else {
        s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), ::isspace), s.end());
        vec.push_back( s );
    }
}
```

For a discussion on how to remove whitespaces from a string see also : [Remove spaces from std::string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83439/remove-spaces-from-stdstring-in-c)