# How to take input of a string with whitespace in c++

Tags: c++

Why I can't take inputs of a string using gets,getline and cin.getline.when I  debugg it seems that compiler skips those lines.here's my code-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1,s2;
    char *p;
    int n,m,i;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int j=0;
        getline (cin,s1);
        getline (cin,s2);
        cout<<s1<<"\n";
        while(s1[j]!='\0')
        {
            if(s1[j]==' ')
            {

                s1.erase(s1[j]);

            }
            j++;
        }

    }
    cout<<s1<<S2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler isn't skipping anything (well, maybe that undefined S2 variable at the bottom of your code). Regardless, this is screaming for example input, desired output, and actual output in your question.

Comment: You need to tell us what you do. What did you input to your program ? What happened ? What did you expect to happen ? Which of all these lines are the lines that the "compiler skips" ?

Comment: What is `while(s1[j]!='\0')` supposed to do?  It is certainly not a reliable way of iterating to the end.

Comment: Here is a better way to remove spaces from a string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/83538/104774

Comment: sample input: s1="I am Dipto" . and i need "Iamdipto"without quotation.But i am getting nothing in output . compiler is skiping     getline(cin,s1) and     getline(cin,s2) lines.

Comment: You're mixing `cin >> ...` with `getline`, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739937/using-getlinecin-s-after-cin

Answer (score 0):

What about **j** variable, it isn't set to **zero** when next for-loop iteration begin, so in second iteration you work with **garbage**.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `cin`, it stores every character entered in memory until it encounters a newline character. This block of memory is called the input buffer.
when you take the input for 'n' the return key is in the cin buffer.

You should use `cin.ignore` to get rid of this newline.

Before `getline (cin,s1);` add `cin.ignore` statement